# Adding self-numerating entries in Word for functional requirements

Tags: microsoft-word

I have to write tables in word for functional requirements specifications. The current situation looks like this

```
3.4 Interface requirements

| F-1-1 | This is the first requirement 
| F-1-2 | This is the second requirement

3.5 Computational requirements

| F-2-1 | This is another requirement 
| F-2-2 | This is another another requirement     
| F-2-3 | This is another another requirement
```

My question is: is there a way to create the first and second number automatically, so I don't have to renumber everything if I happen to add or remove a new entry or whole section?

Note that I do know about fields, but fields don't update automatically. It would require me to constantly refresh

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a MultiLevel List Style and two paragraph styles.

Using SEQ field codes is easier to control, and you only really have to update the field codes each time you "publish" your document.

But for the list style,

1. Create a paragraph style called `flist1` and format the font and font size (at least).
2. Create another paragraph style called `flist2` and base it on flist1
3. Go to Home->Paragraph->Multilevel List->Define New MultiLevel List...
4. In the dialog box, click the More... button at the bottom left

Select "1" in the *Click Level to Modify*

You're aiming to have Level 1 set up like this:

[image: (Define new multilevel list dialog for Level 1)]

so...

1. Clear the contents of the *Enter formatting for number* box
2. In the box, type `F-`
3. In the Number style for this level, select 1,2,3... A greyed "1" should appear in the box above so you see `F-1`
4. After `F-1`, type `-1` so you have `F-1-1`
5. In *Link Level To Style*, select the style `flist1`
6. In *List num field list name* type `flist`
7. Ensure *Start at* is 1
8. In *Follow number with*, select `Nothing`
9. In *Position->Number alignment*, select Left
10. In *Position->Aligned at*, type 0

To ensure all the numbers are aligned in the same way...

1. Click *Set for all Levels...", ensure all the values in the boxes contain 0, and click OK.

Now select "2" in the *Click Level to Modify*

You're aiming to have Level 2 set up like this:

[image: (Define new multilevel list dialog for Level 1]

1. Clear the contents of the *Enter formatting for number* box
2. In the box, type `F-`
3. In *Include level number from* select `Level 1` so you see `F-1`
4. After `F-1`, type `-` so you have `F-1-`
5. In the Number style for this level, select 1,2,3... A greyed "1" should appear in the box above so you see `F-1-1`
6. In *Link Level To Style*, select the style `flist2`
7. **Important: Ensure *Start at* is 2**
8. In *Follow number with*, select `Nothing`

Click OK.

Now apply the paragraph style flist1 to each paragraph where you want the first number to increment (so you get F-1-1, F-2-1 etc.) and flist2 to the other paragraphs. If they are all in column 1 of Word tables, you could select column 1, apply flist2, then select the first cell in the column and apply flist1.

In Word 2016/9 it is possible to go back into the multi level numbering box and change stuff if you get it wrong, which is important because it's very easy to get it wrong at the beginning.